# How can I undo Permanent flag in Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, uninstallation

I created a setup project using Visual Studio 2010.  I accidentally checked the "Permanent" property on one of my dlls, not realizing what I was doing.  From [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cc36436e-dfc2-49c3-a61f-18d2aab24611/visual-studio-2008-setup-project-not-deleting-files-out-of-system-folder-when-uninstalling?forum=winformssetup), I've learned once you turn that setting on, turning it off will not fix the problem.  The file I originally marked Permanent will never be removed on an uninstall even though I've changed the Permanent property back to false.  But, there's gotta be a way, right?  There has to be something in the registry but I'm not finding anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a search for my dll in the whole registry and deleted every node with a reference to it.  I'm not sure which one did the trick.  None of the property names were obvious enough to say that the file was "permanent".